# Problema al usar Insert into

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola estoy ejecutando el siguiente procedimiento y quisiera que al mismo tiempo los datos se inserten una una nueva tabla llamada **sop_piq_log**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[USP_BUSCAR_NUM_PIQ](
    @PIQ INT,
    @CMP varchar(15)
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@PIQ = 0 )
    BEGIN
        SELECT sp.*
        FROM [sop_piq] sp with(nolock)
        WHERE sp.cmp = @CMP  and sp.[status] in (2,3)
        ORDER BY sp.[status] desc, sp.piq_number

        INSERT INTO sop_piq_log([id], [oa], [date_ws], [hour_ws], [name], [type_document], [number_document], [cellphone], [age], [hcl], [oncological], [smoker], [diagnostic], [diagnostic_name], [region], [hospitalazation_type], [medical_report], [date_estimated], [duration_estimated], [hour_estimated], [created_at], [updated_at], [piq_number], [status], [cmp])
        SELECT [id], [oa], [date_ws], [hour_ws], [name], [type_document], [number_document], [cellphone], [age], [hcl], [oncological], [smoker], [diagnostic], [diagnostic_name], [region], [hospitalazation_type], [medical_report], [date_estimated], [duration_estimated], [hour_estimated], [created_at], [updated_at], [piq_number], [status], [cmp]
        FROM [sop_piq]
    END
    
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT sp.* FROM [sop_piq] sp with(nolock)
        WHERE piq_number = @PIQ AND sp.cmp = @CMP
    END
END
```

Sin embargo no logro que los datos se inserten en la tabla **sop_piq_log**

Gracias por su ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el título decís _error_... ¿cuál error? Además, ¿qué motor de base de datos estás utilizando? Especificalo en las etiquetas, y modificá el título. Lee [ask].

Comment: Ya hice la correcion del titulo. El problema que tengo es que no se estan insertando los datos en la nueva tabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución, pasa por ejecutar lo mismo que tienes en el procedimiento pero fuera de el, ya que no parece tener muchos problemas su codificación.

- **Primer paso**

  INSERT INTO sop_piq_log(id
  , oa
  , date_ws
  , hour_ws
  , name
  , type_document
  , number_document
  , cellphone
  , age
  , hcl
  , oncological
  , smoker
  , diagnostic
  , diagnostic_name
  , region
  , hospitalazation_type
  , medical_report
  , date_estimated
  , duration_estimated
  , hour_estimated
  , created_at
  , updated_at
  , piq_number
  , status
  , cmp)
  SELECT top(1)
  id
  , oa
  , date_ws
  , hour_ws
  , name
  , type_document
  , number_document
  , cellphone
  , age
  , hcl
  , oncological
  , smoker
  , diagnostic
  , diagnostic_name
  , region
  , hospitalazation_type
  , medical_report
  , date_estimated
  , duration_estimated
  , hour_estimated
  , created_at
  , updated_at
  , piq_number
  , status
  , cmp
  FROM sop_piq sp;

Si la inserción es válida, tendrás una fila más en `sp_piq_log`.

Si no es correcta, te mostrará el error que sea. Bien porque la definición de las columnas no es adecuada, o bien porque van `Nulos`, o alguna restricción esta funcionando.

Con el error, si se diera el caso, puedes editar la pregunta y pegarlo.

- **Segundo paso**

El paso de parámetros al procedimiento.

```
exec [dbo].[USP_BUSCAR_NUM_PIQ] 0, '23529'
```

Esto tal cuál está debería de duplicarte las lineas de `23529`. Fíjate que lo he pasado como un varchar entre apóstrofes, que es lo que espera el procedimiento.

Por otro lado, el procedimiento debería de tener una restricción where, igual que la  Select. Y en vez de usar el hint With(NoLock), quizá deberías de revisar el uso de [Set Transacion Isolation Level Read Uncommmitted](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15);

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[USP_BUSCAR_NUM_PIQ](
    @PIQ INT,
    @CMP varchar(15)
)
AS
BEGIN

    IF(@PIQ = 0 )
    BEGIN
        SELECT sp.*
        FROM [sop_piq] sp 
        WHERE sp.cmp = @CMP  and sp.[status] in (2,3)
        ORDER BY sp.[status] desc, sp.piq_number


INSERT INTO sop_piq_log(id
                      , oa
                      , date_ws
                      , hour_ws
                      , name
                      , type_document
                      , number_document
                      , cellphone
                      , age
                      , hcl
                      , oncological
                      , smoker
                      , diagnostic
                      , diagnostic_name
                      , region
                      , hospitalazation_type
                      , medical_report
                      , date_estimated
                      , duration_estimated
                      , hour_estimated
                      , created_at
                      , updated_at
                      , piq_number
                      , status
                      , cmp)
SELECT id
     , oa
     , date_ws
     , hour_ws
     , name
     , type_document
     , number_document
     , cellphone
     , age
     , hcl
     , oncological
     , smoker
     , diagnostic
     , diagnostic_name
     , region
     , hospitalazation_type
     , medical_report
     , date_estimated
     , duration_estimated
     , hour_estimated
     , created_at
     , updated_at
     , piq_number
     , status
     , cmp
       FROM sop_piq sp
       WHERE sp.cmp = @CMP  and sp.[status] in (2,3)
    END
    
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT sp.* FROM [sop_piq] sp 
        WHERE piq_number = @PIQ AND sp.cmp = @CMP
    END
END
```